# How do I parse an Array of JSON objects in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, parsing, object

I am having problems parsing a json in C++.

```
{"id":1,"name":"Pablo","client_type":"customer","uid":"c63bab66",
"credit":10000.0,"valid_user":true,"can_clean":false,"can_detach":false,
"can_set_temp":false,"category":"VIP","category_low_percentage":20,
"category_medium_percentage":20,"category_high_percentage":20,
"bottle_holders":
[{"dispenser_index":8,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":7,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":6,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":5,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":4,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":3,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":2,"can_complementary_drink":true},
 {"dispenser_index":1,"can_complementary_drink":true}],
"errors":[]}
```

and this is the way I'm trying to parse it.

```
 json_unpack(usr,"{s:s, s:s, s:i, s:f, s:b, s:b, s:b, s:s, s:i, s:i, s:i, s:o, s:o}", "uid", &juid, "name", &jname,
                        "id", &id, "credit", &credit, "can_clean", &jcan_clean, "can_detach", &jcan_detach, 
                        "can_set_temp", &jcan_set_temp, "category", &jcategory, "category_low_percetage", &category_low_perc, 
                        "category_medium_percetage", &category_medium_perc, "category_high_percetage", &category_high_perc,
                        "bottle_holders", &jbottle_holders, "errors", &jerrors);
```

The problem is that when I try to get the lenght of the array of objects "jbottle_holders" it is "0".
My guess is that I should change "s:o" for something that would properly describe an array of objects. 
What do you think?

Comment: Use [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) or some other C++ JSON library... not [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) which is a C library